# How do you unlock the Bullet as a playable character?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I heard a while back that you could play as a BulletKin in Enter the Gungeon but I don't know how. Is it a cheat or hack? Or is there something you have to do?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed on the [Enter the Gungeon wiki](http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/The_Bullet), the Bullet is a hidden character.

After you've beaten at least one Past from any other Gungeoneer, you will notice that Red-Caped Bulletkin will start to spawn. Even though these Bulletkin hold guns, they do not actually shoot, and they also do not deal any contact damage (unless they are Jammed, of course). If you avoid killing this special Bulletkin for a few seconds, it will disappear on its own. After you've encountered 5 of these caped Bulletkin and let them all go without killing them, the Bullet will be unlocked as a playable character.

The Bullet is a great character. He does not start with a gun - instead, he starts with Blasphemy, a sword that can "erase" bullets when they are slashed. If the Bullet has maximum health (fully healed), the sword will also shoot a bean sword projectile.